# Erro ao conectar app com Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Estou tentando conectar meu App ao Firebase, já segui os passos dados no próprio site, além de ver alguns vídeos de outros autores, porém me deparo sempre com o seguinte problema:

```
Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
```

Esse arquivo já foi baixado e inclusive adicionado à pasta exigida, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:
[image: Arquivo GoogleService-Info.plist adicionado ao projeto]

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro já foi corrigido, além de arrastar o arquivo GoogleService-Info.plist para a devida pasta, é necessário também indicar seu diretório no painel Show in file inspector, além de marcar o projeto na opção Target Membership, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

Answer (score 0):

Selecione o arquivo e na aba da direita do Xcode, na opção Target Membership você seleciona. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o link no post que eu encontrei essa resposta: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/5